# Angular - storing checkbox values, and displaying them

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, wordpress

Suppose that, you have 27 checkboxes, let's call them 'categories'. These checkboxes are in one section, you can select them multiple, and save.

The eseence is: if you save the form, the categories will be added to your profile, in MySQL.

My question is:

- How I should name the models,
- How I should store de values after sending the form

I had a solution for this, I saved the nth of the categories, then clicked them back at loading, but that's not the best.

Here is the code:

```
 $scope.getSelectedCats = function()  //Returning array: [1,4,5,6]
 {
   $return_array = [];
   $i = 0;

   if($scope.whoareu.develop){ $return_array[$i] = 1; $i++;}
   if($scope.whoareu.design){ $return_array[$i] = 2; $i++;}
   if($scope.whoareu.produce){ $return_array[$i] = 3; $i++;}
   if($scope.whoareu.repair){ $return_array[$i] = 4; $i++;}
   [...]

   return $return_array;

 }
```

HTML

```
  <p>
    <input ng-model="whoareu.develop" type="checkbox" value=1 id="WAY8" name="whoareu"  />
    <label for="WAY8">Develop</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input ng-model="whoareu.design" type="checkbox" value=2 id="WAY9" name="whoareu"  />
    <label for="WAY9">Design</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input ng-model="whoareu.produce" type="checkbox" value=3 id="WAY10" name="whoareu" />
    <label for="WAY10">Produce</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input ng-model="whoareu.repair" type="checkbox" value=4 id="WAY11" name="whoareu" />
    <label for="WAY11">Repair</label>
  </p>
  [...]
```

And last, a very ugly solution for loading checks:

```
  <?php
  //$dbData = Data row from mysql, in object, by Wordpress
  echo "setTimeout(function(){";
  foreach(explode(',', $dbData->interested_in) as $val)
  {
    //echo "$('input:checkbox[name=whatareu]').filter('[value=$val]').click();";
    echo "$('input:checkbox[name=whatareu]').eq($val-1).click();";
  }
  echo "}, 1000);";
  ?>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Also what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Post updated, and i'm using angular 1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem well, see my snippet. If you want, you could create some mapping function `setDefaultState(basedOn)` which set `checked` in model `checkboxs`.

If the problem is that data is lost after you leave the controller, you should use some singleton storage like Angular's factories, and storage the checked categories there.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('FrameController', ['$injector',
  function($injector) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.checkboxs = [{
      id: 'WAY8',
      label: 'Develop',
      checked: true
    }, {
      id: 'WAY9',
      label: 'Design'
    }]

    angular.extend(vm, {
      save: save
    })

    function save() {
      // API call
      console.log('checked: ', vm.checkboxs.filter(function(c) {
        return c.checked
      }).map(function(c) {
        return {
          id: c.id
        }
      }));
    }

  }
]);

setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="FrameController as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="checkbox in vm.checkboxs">
        <input ng-model="checkbox.checked" type="checkbox" id="{{checkbox.id}}" name="whoareu" />
        <label for="{{checkbox.id}}">{{checkbox.label}}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="vm.save()">
      Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```